Start new app command hanging, not throwing any errors
I'm on Node 22.11.0 with NPM 10.9.0 and Shopify CLI 3.70.0.
The screenshot is of shopify app init not completing. I've been stuck there for over 10 minutes each time I retry the command differently. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the CLI with no success. The command is not throwing any errors, even after terminating it with Ctrl-C, meaning I'm unable to debug what exactly is wrong.
What could be the problem?

UPDATE
Here's the relevant output after executing the command with --verbose.
The first lines:

The last lines:


Not a real 'solution' but I worked around just by changing my node version for this via NVM to nvm use lts/iron

Today, the Shopify CLI service was generating an error for a period of time—at least, I encountered this error, and it later resolved itself.
Try using Yarn instead of NPM, switch to Node version 20 or 18, and repeat the process.
If there’s no result, the fact that it takes 10 minutes to execute indicates something is wrong.
From what I can see, it looks like you’re running the Shopify CLI on Linux. In that case, the simplest approach is to install a different version of Node or clear the Shopify package cache to ensure there are no errors.
Question:
Does this only happen with the shopify app init command, or does it also happen with other commands like shopify theme info?

shopify theme info is working. Returning with no errors.
